# Make the turtle move faster

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running the `draw_square.cpp` node from  the `turtlesim/tutorials` package. The emulated turtle moves as expected.

**Question:** How can I change the source code in `draw_square.cpp`  to make the turtle move faster?

[image: turtlesim/draw_square]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292523/make-the-turtle-move-faster/) by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2018-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The callback function `commandTurtle` ([source code](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/blob/821a8ae33c6da1a70e21453392f6980380f670f8/turtlesim/tutorials/draw_square.cpp#L44-L50)) publishes the twist message, which defines the linear and angular velocity of the turtle.

The interface of the functions looks like `void commandTurtle(ros::Publisher twist_pub, float linear, float angular)`. The `float linear` argument defines the forward velocity of the turtle.

Therefore, try changing the argument passed to the `commandTurtle` function when the `void forward`  ([source code](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/blob/821a8ae33c6da1a70e21453392f6980380f670f8/turtlesim/tutorials/draw_square.cpp#L87-L98))

---

Originally posted by [nathan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34948/nathan/) with karma: 111 on 2018-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2